# spaCy: Incorrect token.vector calculation

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

The code:

```
doc = nlp(u"Apples and oranges are similar. Boots and hippos aren't.")
print doc[0],doc[2],doc[6],doc[8]
apples = doc[0]
oranges = doc[2]
boots = doc[6]
hippos = doc[8]
print(apples.similarity(oranges))
print(boots.similarity(hippos))
```

Result:

```
Apples oranges Boots hippos
0.0
0.0
```

[Code is From Here.](https://github.com/cytora/pycon-nlp-in-10-lines/blob/master/00_spacy_intro.ipynb)

[Opened a GitHub Issue.](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/1092)

[Documentation of spaCy](https://spacy.io/docs/api/token#similarity) says that higher the similarity higher is the value returned but the similarity of apples and oranges is 0.
Why?

### EDIT

Well, the code below explains that why the similarity is calculated incorrectly. **It is due to incorrect vector calculations:**

```
doc = nlp(u'apples is apple. orange is not. oranges is nothing')
def dot_prd(a, b):
    ans = 0
    sa, sb = 0, 0
    for i in range(len(a)):
        ans += a[i]*b[i]
        sa += a[i]*a[i]
        sb += b[i]*b[i]
    sa = sa**0.5
    sb = sb**0.5
    return ans/(sa*sb)

print doc[0], doc[2], doc[4], doc[8]

print dot_prd(doc[0].vector, doc[2].vector), dot_prd(doc[0].vector,      doc[4].vector), dot_prd(doc[0].vector,doc[8].vector), dot_prd(doc[4].vector,    doc[8].vector)

print doc[0].similarity(doc[2]), doc[0].similarity(doc[4]),    doc[0].similarity(doc[8]), doc[4].similarity(doc[8])
```

Output:

```
apples apple orange oranges
0.750411317806 0.51238496547 nan nan   #Resuults of cosine-simlarity
0.750411349583 0.512384940626 0.0 0.0  #token.simlarity()
```

The `doc[8].vector` is all zeroes. So, why is the vector for 'oranges' token calculated as all-0s? 
The vector for 'orange' & 'apple' is calculated correctly. More importantly, the vector for 'apples' is also calculated correctly.  So, why is 'oranges' a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Because the word vector of 2 token ("oranges" and "hippos") is zero (This is model problem)

You can check by print the vector of this token:

print(oranges.vector)
print(hippos.vector)

Comment: Yeah, I figured. I added that edit on the GitHub issue but forgot to update it here. Thanks anyways.

Comment: all caught up now.